# how can i create a new type by merging the others?

Tags: typescript

how can i create a new type by merging the others?

`export type Align = 'center' | 'left' | 'right'

export type Breakpoints = ‘sm’ | ‘md’`

I would like to unite the Align and Breakpoints types to obtain a new type with the following result:

`export type Aligns   = ‘sm-center ’ | ‘sm-left ’ |  ‘sm-right ’ | ‘md-center’ …`

is this possible with typescript?

not develop any solution

Answer (score 2):

[`Template literal types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

```
type Aligns = `${Breakpoints}_${Align}`
```

is equivalent to

```
type Aligns = 'sm_center' | 'sm_left' | 'sm_right' | 'md_center' | 'md_left' | 'md_right'
```

Comment: Not a problem! Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if you believe it to be correct :) thanks!